# JavaScript Captured Event Listener and MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

So I'm trying to change some of my JavaScript

From this

```
content.forumobserver = content.build.forumobserver = function() {
    var target = document.querySelector('#content-padding');
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation, idx, mutated) {
            if(mutation.addedNodes.length === 21) {
                for(var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                    if(mutation.addedNodes[i].id === 'post_container') {
                        // update
                        content.c_page = document.querySelector('.page_current');
                        content.t_url = content.c_page.href;
                        content.t_page = content.t_url.replace(content.regex.url, '$3');
                        // reload
                        content.init(options);
                        // page is loaded
                        observer.disconnect();
                    };
                };
            };
        });
    });
    $.each(document.querySelectorAll('.yui3-pjax'), function(idx, pjax) {
       pjax.addEventListener('click', function() {
           observer.observe(target, {
               childList: true
           });
       });
    });
};
```

To this

```
content.forumobserver = content.build.forumobserver = function() {
    var target = document.querySelector('#content-padding');
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation, idx, mutated) {
            if(mutation.addedNodes.length === 21) {
                for(var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                    if(mutation.addedNodes[i].id === 'post_container') {
                        // update
                        content.c_page = document.querySelector('.page_current');
                        content.t_url = content.c_page.href;
                        content.t_page = content.t_url.replace(content.regex.url, '$3');
                        // reload
                        content.init(prefs);
                        // page is loaded
                        observer.disconnect();
                    };
                };
            };
        });
    });
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        if(evt.target.classList.contains('yui3-pjax')) {
            observer.observe(target, {
                childList: true
            });
        };
    }, true);
};
```

The only problem is that the latter of the two, the observer doesn't disconnect when it gets to the point where I want it to. I call the content.forumobserver() in the content.init() function. The reason I know it's not disconnecting instead of say adding multiple event listeners to the body is because if I add an if-statement to check an initialized value, then call the content.forumobserver() and set the initialized to true in the content.init() function the MutationObserver still re-adds all the content, but then for each additional page loaded the content added is doubled, 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on.

So how can I make the MutationObserver disconnect after the content loads from the captured event instead of having to explicitly bind the click events to the yui3-pjax anchors?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using,

```
content.forumobserver = content.build.forumobserver = function(evt) {
    if(evt.target.classList.contains('yui3-pjax') || evt.target.parentNode.classList.contains('yui3-pjax')) {
        var target = document.querySelector('#content-padding');
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation, idx, mutated) {
                if(mutation.addedNodes.length === 21) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                        if(mutation.addedNodes[i].id === 'post_container') {
                            // update
                            content.c_page = document.querySelector('.page_current');
                            content.t_url = content.c_page.href;
                            content.t_page = content.t_url.replace(content.regex.url, '$3');
                            // reload
                            content.init(options);
                            // page is loaded
                            observer.disconnect();
                        };
                    };
                };
            });
        });
        observer.observe(target, {
            childList: true
        });
    };
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', content.forumobserver, true);
```